# Making changes during a optimization loop, IPOPT

Tags: optimization, julia, julia-jump, ipopt

I am currently working with some complicated problems where I want to make a small change to my objective function (just increasing a constant) if some statement is not satisfied in an iteration. I want to check this while IPOPT is running (before optimize! (model)is finished) Is this possible? Can I use the callback function to change the objective function from one iteration to the next?

Comment: No. That would be a terrible hack. Better is to add the logic to the model itself. (You may end up with an MINLP).

Comment: You could use callback with Julia with commercial solvers (they cost tons of money but are free if you are in academia) - this works pretty well and stable.

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel As you say this works pretty well and stable, please show how to change the objective inside a callback.  (Hint: this does not work pretty and stable as it is not possible).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen you are right that my comment requires more clarification. In a callback you can add new constraints. You could have an objective such as  `@objective(m, Min, a[1] * x[1] + a[2] * x[2])`  where both `x`  and `a` are `@variable` (such model formulation is supported in Gurobi). Assuming all values are positive, adding new in callback constraints inequality regarding `a` would have the exact effect of changing the objective function.

Comment: Making the model non-convex is in general not a good approach. Also, note that Gurobi only allows globally valid constraints to be added. I still think the better answer to this question is: no this cannot be done (except in some very special cases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPOPT has a callback implemented, but it gives you access only to a handful information, see for instance ( https://github.com/jump-dev/Ipopt.jl ):

```
using JuMP, Ipopt, Test
model = Model(Ipopt.Optimizer)
set_silent(model)
@variable(model, x >= 1)
@objective(model, Min, x + 0.5)
x_vals = Float64[]
function my_callback(
   alg_mod::Cint,
   iter_count::Cint,
   obj_value::Float64,
   inf_pr::Float64,
   inf_du::Float64,
   mu::Float64,
   d_norm::Float64,
   regularization_size::Float64,
   alpha_du::Float64,
   alpha_pr::Float64,
   ls_trials::Cint,
)
   push!(x_vals, callback_value(model, x))
   @test isapprox(obj_value, 1.0 * x_vals[end] + 0.5, atol = 1e-1)
   # return `true` to keep going, or `false` to terminate the optimization.
   return iter_count < 1
end
MOI.set(model, Ipopt.CallbackFunction(), my_callback)
optimize!(model)
@test MOI.get(model, MOI.TerminationStatus()) == MOI.INTERRUPTED
@test length(x_vals) == 2
```

However, you cannot modify the problem. One of the main reasons is that IPOPT is not coded in Julia, so a conversion in C is done along the way.

The only solution I see is to use a flexible modeling structure (one that would let you modify the objective) and a solver coded in pure Julia. Still, it is a bit of work.

For instance, if you deal with unconstrained optimization problems you could use `lbfgs` as follows:

```
using ADNLPModels, JSOSolvers, ForwardDiff, NLPModels

# Using ADNLPModel for its flexibility.
# But we need to deactivate the pre-computation done on the objective function
# https://juliasmoothoptimizers.github.io/tutorials/generic-adnlpmodels/
struct GenericGradientBackend <: ADNLPModels.ADBackend end
GenericGradientBackend(args...; kwargs...) = GenericGradientBackend()

function ADNLPModels.gradient!(::GenericGradientBackend, g, f, x)
  return ForwardDiff.gradient!(g, f, x)
end

nlp = ADNLPModel(
  x -> 100 * (x[2] - 2)^2 + 2 * (x[1] - 1)^2 + (x[1] - x[2]^2)^2,
  [-1.2; 1.0],
  gradient_backend = GenericGradientBackend,
)

# Then, we define the callback
function cb(nlp, solver, stats)
  @show stats.iter
  @show solver.x
  if stats.iter > 1
    nlp.f = x -> 2 * (x[2] - 2)^2 + 100 * (x[1] - 1)^2 + (x[1] - x[2]^2)^2
  end
  @show obj(nlp, solver.x)
end
# call JSOSolvers.lbfgs https://juliasmoothoptimizers.github.io/tutorials/introduction-to-jsosolvers/
stats = lbfgs(nlp, callback = cb, verbose = 1)
```

the output will be

```
julia> stats = lbfgs(nlp, callback = cb, verbose = 1)
[ Info:   iter      f(x)      ‖∇f‖      ∇fᵀd      bk  
stats.iter = 0
solver.x = [-1.2, 1.0]
obj(nlp, solver.x) = 114.52000000000001
[ Info:      0   1.1e+02   1.9e+02  -3.7e+04       6
stats.iter = 1
solver.x = [-1.1459328, 1.7831552000000002]
obj(nlp, solver.x) = 32.62282328590102
[ Info:      1   3.3e+01   2.1e+01  -2.2e+00       0
stats.iter = 2
solver.x = [-1.0645542968025667, 1.8450655818506445]
obj(nlp, solver.x) = 446.25681758709055
[ Info:      2   3.1e+01   1.7e+01  -5.0e+00      25
stats.iter = 3
solver.x = [-1.0645542967686918, 1.8450655818604536]
obj(nlp, solver.x) = 446.25681757311787
[ Info:      3   4.5e+02   4.2e+02  -3.1e+03       1
stats.iter = 4
solver.x = [1.9246380432427963, 2.7281329116323207]
obj(nlp, solver.x) = 117.00501528447751
[ Info:      4   1.2e+02   1.8e+02  -1.9e+02       0
stats.iter = 5
solver.x = [0.9801608161355717, 2.3095374587434887]
obj(nlp, solver.x) = 19.186582034724903
[ Info:      5   1.9e+01   4.3e+01  -4.8e+00       0
stats.iter = 6
solver.x = [0.9652544626973018, 2.189462921736651]
obj(nlp, solver.x) = 14.849879523336808
[ Info:      6   1.5e+01   3.7e+01  -1.9e+01       0
stats.iter = 7
solver.x = [1.0002184791527038, 1.6363671414275927]
obj(nlp, solver.x) = 3.078398087147021
[ Info:      7   3.1e+00   1.0e+01  -2.1e+00       0
stats.iter = 8
solver.x = [1.0089309580533612, 1.4229017930719876]
obj(nlp, solver.x) = 1.7057450643634193
[ Info:      8   1.7e+00   3.5e+00  -4.3e-01       0
stats.iter = 9
solver.x = [1.0053404604019518, 1.2982558231123305]
obj(nlp, solver.x) = 1.4503155493415034
[ Info:      9   1.5e+00   7.8e-01  -2.4e-02       0
stats.iter = 10
solver.x = [1.0064110790068321, 1.2657336397712304]
obj(nlp, solver.x) = 1.4372277943232419
[ Info:     10   1.4e+00   1.2e-01  -8.8e-04       1
stats.iter = 11
solver.x = [1.0047305130737216, 1.2632117110472276]
obj(nlp, solver.x) = 1.4372011985565385
[ Info:     11   1.4e+00   2.4e-01  -3.3e-04       0
stats.iter = 12
solver.x = [1.00584984478302, 1.2615152914236158]
obj(nlp, solver.x) = 1.4370347773092513
[ Info:     12   1.4e+00   1.5e-03  -4.5e-08       0
stats.iter = 13
solver.x = [1.0058545642521763, 1.2614703004604053]
obj(nlp, solver.x) = 1.4370347544382267
[ Info:     13   1.4e+00   9.6e-06  -2.5e-12       0
stats.iter = 14
solver.x = [1.005854516585087, 1.26146995704064]
obj(nlp, solver.x) = 1.4370347544370015
[ Info:     14   1.4e+00   5.6e-07
"Execution stats: first-order stationary"
```